# unity3d OnMouseDown function

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity3D. I am trying to do a simple thing. But not able to do this. I have a .obj file which is a 3d key file. I do the followings:

1. Import this key (to assets) in unity3D
2. Add this key to scene (from assets to hierarchy)
3. Add a script to this key
4. Add the `OnMouseDown()` function to this script as  follows -

   ```
   void OnMouseDown() 
   {
       Debug.Log ("clicked...");
   }
   ```

But when I click the key no message is showing in console. Please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: There is a collider attached to your object?

Comment: Yes there is a collider is attached to the object

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure the gameobject is not at layer "Ignore Raycast"
2. Use the following inside your update function to see raycasting is working fine.

   void Update () {

   ```
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
              RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
             Debug.Log ("Name = " + hit.collider.name);
             Debug.Log ("Tag = " + hit.collider.tag);
             Debug.Log ("Hit Point = " + hit.point);
             Debug.Log ("Object position = " + hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position);
             Debug.Log ("--------------");
            }
          }
   }
   ```

Comment: Here we get the information about the object which is clicked. But I want to know how can I modify that object property such as how can we change the x position of that object?

Comment: use can access the x position by object.transform.position.x, alternatively you can translate the object in x direction using transform.translate(yourposition,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

The OnMouseDown and it's related functions are all actually older systems. The newer system to use for this is the event system.

Specifically to get mouse clicks you would implement this interface in a class:
http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTriggerType.PointerClick.html

But there is actually an easier way to do it without code.
Using this component:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html

You can then visually forward the mouse click event to something else.

If you don't fully follow what I have said so far, the thing to really start at is learning the UI system. You can find video tutorials here:
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-canvas

And just to make it clear, the UI system is not just for UI. The UI system runs off an EventSystem which is what you want to use to forward input events to any object 3D or 2D in the entire scene. The UI tutorials will explain the usage of that EventSystem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a collider to the 3d object if you want to fire it with [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html):

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider.
>
> This event is sent to all scripts of the Collider or GUIElement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like by override click function

```
public override void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log("OnPointerClick called.");
}
```