# mouseDown and mouseUp on certain objects in android in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I try to make a game for android where you have press and hold buttons to move and lift to stop. However, I couldn't make it work on android, because the OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp only works for PC. Is there any way to do it in android? Here is my code:

```
﻿using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class buttonRight : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody player;
    public float speed;
    private bool clicking;
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("click");
        clicking = true;
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        if (clicking == true)
            player.velocity = movement * speed;
    }
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Debug.Log("stop click");
        clicking = false;
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        player.velocity = movement * 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put some effort in searching the web first, it's full of resources you need. Look into the [docs of Input Class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html), click on CTRL+F, type in "**touch**" and read every link that gets highlighted.

Comment: "OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp only works for PC" - that is not true, it should work also on device. Unity3D engine converts OnMouseUp etc to be called also on coresponding touch phase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unity3d OnMouseDown function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720531/unity3d-onmousedown-function)

Comment: Hey guys - this is a MILLION TIMES DUPLICATE QUESTION. it's very important to CLOSE such questions.  A HUGE problem is developing with the low quality of Unity3D tag questions on this site.

Comment: Jerry - OP forgot to put it in Update  :)

Answer (score 0):

A thousand times question. Well, answer is `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseUp` execute only once and you are trying to use them as `OnMouseDown` executes per frame.

You can do something like,

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
bool clicking = false;

void Update ()
{
    if (clicking == true)
        _rb.velocity = movement * 5;
    else
        _rb.velocity = movement * 0;
}

void OnMouseDown ()
{
    Debug.Log ("click");
    clicking = true;

}

void OnMouseUp ()
{
    Debug.Log ("stop click");
    clicking = false;

}
```